# activejdbc - store fetched database metadata

Tags: activejdbc

Is it possible to store somehow fetched metadata from database?
I need to run this process many times and it works too long. It would be
great to have possibility to load these metadata from any local object
and refresh it when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by caching, please see this docs page: http://javalite.io/caching

Comment: I understand that I can cache data and operations on models but I need to cache and store/load metadata of tables. Is it possible by provided cache methods/annotation?

Comment: what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: It would be great to perform fetching metadata in the same way as it works for instrumentation process. In my case fetching metadata takes too much time and it is not efficient way to execute automated tests. If I want tu run even one simple unit test then fetching operation must be performed even if my database was not changed.

Comment: usually unit tests are perfomed in the same instance of JVM, so fetching of metadata is only done once. Can you run your tests from a single process?

Comment: Problem is while test development and fixing problems then it must be performed many times :-(

Comment: maybe you need to investigate why fetching metadata is taking a long time. In our projects we also have thousands of tests, but no delays